# Why can't add more than one custom button?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gtk3, glade

I try to add 3 buttons inside a Gtk.Box, this Box was created in my Window design (with Glade). See the code;

```
    # Button for IPCamera (MJpeg stream)    
    self.buttonIPCam1 = Gtk.Button()
    self.buttonIPCam1.add(self.imageIPCam)
    self.buttonIPCam1.connect("clicked", self.triggerIPCam1)
    self.buttonIPCam1.props.relief = Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE
    self.placeButtonCameras.add(self.buttonIPCam1)
    self.buttonIPCam2 = Gtk.Button()
    self.buttonIPCam2.add(self.imageIPCam)
    self.buttonIPCam2.connect("clicked", self.triggerIPCam2)
    self.buttonIPCam2.props.relief = Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE
    self.placeButtonCameras.add(self.buttonIPCam2) 
    self.buttonIPCam3 = Gtk.Button()
    self.buttonIPCam3.add(self.imageIPCam)
    self.buttonIPCam3.connect("clicked", self.triggerIPCam3)
    self.buttonIPCam3.props.relief = Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE
    self.placeButtonCameras.add(self.buttonIPCam3)
    
    self.placeButtonCameras.show_all()
```

Only one button with icon is displayed and got this error message;

```
(app_pre.py:3068): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:30:27.422: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a container of type GtkButton, but the widget is already inside a container of type GtkButton, please remove the widget from its existing container first.
```

I'm beginner and don't known why I can't add more than one Button with Image at time for this container "Box" named; self.placeButtonCameras.

In future, is for adding buttons from a config (0 to 5 cameras possibles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you're adding multiple buttons, but that you're trying to re-use a GtkImage in multiple GtkButtons. Rather than trying to re-use the widget, you should create a new one each time.

In other words, your current code does this:

```
    // somewhere earlier: self.imageIPCam = new Gtk.Image()

    self.buttonIPCam1.add(self.imageIPCam)
    // ...
    self.buttonIPCam2.add(self.imageIPCam)
    // ...
    self.buttonIPCam3.add(self.imageIPCam)
```

To fix it you can do this:

```
    imageIPCam1 = new Gtk.Image()
    self.buttonIPCam1.add(self.imageIPCam1)
    // ...
    imageIPCam2 = new Gtk.Image()
    self.buttonIPCam2.add(self.imageIPCam2)
    // ...
    imageIPCam3 = new Gtk.Image()
    self.buttonIPCam3.add(self.imageIPCam3)
```